# Why my first touch of button doesn't rotate my object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, object

When i hit q or r my pieces dont rotate the first time, but after the second touch they work perfect. Can someone tell my how to fix it? I tried to modify some variables but it doesn't work and I dont know why, I think its maybe of the boolean variables, but I am not sure.
[image: Pieces that i use for rotation]

[The attach of each piece of the game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usjK1.png)

Here is my code:

```
private bool moving;

private float startPosX;
private float startPosY;
private bool heRotado = false;

private float rotZ = 90;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if(moving){
        Vector3 mousePos;
        mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
        mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos);
        this.gameObject.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(mousePos.x - startPosX, mousePos.y - startPosY, this.gameObject.transform.localPosition.z);
    }
    if (moving)
        Rotate();
    
}

// Funcion para rotar las piezas 
// Con la tecla q se gira hacia la izquierda, con la tecla r se gira hacia la derecha
void Rotate(){
    if (Input.GetKey("r") && !heRotado){
        rotZ += 90;
        gameObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, rotZ);
        heRotado = true;
    }
    if (!Input.GetKey("r") && !Input.GetKey("q")) {
        heRotado = false;
    }

    if (Input.GetKey("q") && !heRotado){
        rotZ -= 90;
        gameObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, rotZ);
        heRotado = true;
    }
}

// Override
public void OnMouseDown(){
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
        Vector3 mousePos;
        mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
        mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos);

        startPosX = mousePos.x - this.transform.localPosition.x;
        startPosY = mousePos.y - this.transform.localPosition.y;
        moving = true;
    }

}
// Override
private void OnMouseUp(){
    moving = false;
}
```

Comment: In the code you posted, the only place you call `Rotate()`, it will not be called as long as `moving` remains set to `false`. The only place in the code you posted where the `moving` variable is set to `true`, is in the `OnMouseDown()` method. So while it's clear why pressing the key the first time doesn't cause rotation, there's nothing in the code you posted that would explain why pressing the key the second time _does_ cause rotation. ...

Comment: ... The `moving` variable would still be set to `false`, and the rotation will still not occur. Please fix your question so it includes a [mcve] that can actually reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are you sure pressing `r` at first does nothing?  The code looks like it would set the rotation to 180 degrees from the identity rotation. Pressing `q` at first looks like it would set the rotation to the identity rotation, so that makes sense it would appear like it does nothing.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Maybe it's best to have asker include this information but i'm 99% sure asker has a collider attached to the gameobject, which calls  OnMouseDown when a mouse click happens on it. But even if that's true, the question needs more information because the described behavior does not match the code...

Comment: I would attach a new image, so that you can see the attributtes that a piece have, and sorry I am new in StackOverflow, dont blame me :(

Comment: Ruzihm you where right the firt time I press R it rotates it 180 degrees, how I can fix it? And first time when I hit q it set to 0, I am new in Unity and making games.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed by changing this line:
`private float rotZ = 0;`

I am so fool, sorry for the problems I caused.